# Efficient one pass algorithm for finding a set of 'N' numbers whos sum is equal to 'M'?

Tags: java, algorithm, random

What must be efficient algorithm for the given problem statement? (java preferred)

Find a set S of N numbers such that their sum is equal to M. Each number in the set S must fall within the given deviation 'D' from the average M/N.

```
int M= 100;
int N= 10;
int D= 3;
```

Here average of M/N = 10. So with deviation of 3, N can be one of the numbers from {7,8,9,10,11,12,13}

Result must be similar to this set:

> 11 11 9 8 11 9 11 11 9 10

Below the is the program, I came up so far:

```
    public class RandomNumberGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int sum = 100;
        int numbers = 10;
        int deviation = 3;

        int iterator = 0;
        int sumTemp = 0;
        int storeArray[] = new int[numbers];
        int average = Math.round((float) sum / (float) numbers);
        int numberOfAttempts = 0;
        int discardedBecauseGreater = 0;
        System.out.println("Average is " + average);

        while (iterator < numbers) {
            int temp = r.nextInt(average + deviation);
            if (temp > average - deviation) {
                storeArray[iterator] = temp;
                sumTemp += temp;
                iterator++;
            }
            if (iterator == numbers) {
                if (sumTemp == sum) {
                    System.out.println("Got the result " + sumTemp);
                    System.out
                            .println("Number of attempts " + numberOfAttempts);
                    System.out.println("Discarded because of greater "
                            + discardedBecauseGreater);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
                        System.out.println(storeArray[i]);
                    }

                    break;
                } else {
                    numberOfAttempts++;
                    sumTemp = 0;
                    iterator = 0;
                }
            }

            if (sumTemp > sum) {
                discardedBecauseGreater++;
                sumTemp = 0;
                iterator = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Comment: FYI http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-that-given-a-set-a-of-n-numbers-and-another-number-x-determines-whether-or-not-there-exist-two-elements-in-s-whose-sum-is-exactly-x/

Comment: With current formulation `{10,10,10,10,..}` is the simplest solution.

Comment: @JohnColeman It isn't subset sum (which I'm assuming is the NP-complete problem you're referring to) because you get to come up with the numbers yourself within some range, not pick them from a set, although the problem doesn't appear to be well-specified enough to answer at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets reformulated the problem: Sample `N` values X<sub>i</sub> so that:

- Sum<sub>i</sub><sup>N</sup> X<sub>i</sub> = 1
- With mean E[X<sub>i</sub>] = 1/N
- Each X<sub>i</sub> fit within +-`d` from mean

If you're able to sample such numbers, then you could re-scale it to whatever `M` you want.

What is described here looks like [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) with somewhat large parameters. Suppose we use Dirichlet distribution with all α<sub>i</sub> equal to the same value `a`. Following link above:

- α<sub>i</sub> = a
- α<sub>0</sub> = N*a
- E[X<sub>i</sub>] = α<sub>i</sub>/α<sub>0</sub> = a / (Na) = 1/N
- Var[X<sub>i</sub>] ~ α<sub>i</sub>/α<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup> = 1/(N<sup>2</sup>a)

So if `a` is large enough, variance would be very small. Take a look at upper right picture at the link with (7,7,7) case. For final tuning we might use acceptance/rejection - if any value is more that `d` way, we throw it out and resample.

Code (some presudocode, actually, my Java is rusty). For sampling from Dirichlet distribution, I'm using well-known approach https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69210/drawing-from-dirichlet-distribution, with Gamma distribution for Java assuming to come from Apache Common library https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/package-tree.html

```
GammaDistribution[] initDirichlet(double a, int N) {
    GammaDistribution[] r = new GammaDistribution[N];
    double scale = 1.0;
    for(int k = 0; k != N; ++k)
        r[k] = new GammaDistribution(a, 1.0);
    }
    return r;
}

void sampleDirichlet(double[] r, GammaDistribution[] g, int N) {
    double s = 0.0;
    for (int k = 0; k != N; ++k) {
        double v = g[k].sample();
        r[k] = v;
        s += v;
    }
    s = 1.0 / s;
    for (int k = 0; k != N; ++k) {
        r[k] *= s;
    }
}

void sample(double[] r, GammaDistribution[] g, int N, double d) {
    double mean = 1.0/(double)N;
    outer:
    for( ;; ) {
        sampleDirichlet(r, g, N);
        for (int k = 0; k != N; ++k) {
            if (Math.Abs(r[k] - mean) > d)
                continue outer; // reject and start over
        }
        break; // accept
    }
}

int use() {
    int N = 10;
    double a = 7.0;
    double d = 0.05;
    GammaDistribution[] g = initDirichlet(a, N);

    double[] r = new double[N];

    sample(r, g, N, d);
    sample(r, g, N, d);
    sample(r, g, N, d);
    sample(r, g, N, d);
    sample(r, g, N, d);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a variation/similar to the water pouring problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_pouring_puzzle

You can choose n cups each of m{i} capacity to pour the desired amount of water.

so choose "n" numbers to sum to "m" .

You can find solutions and tailer it to your use case.

Here is one possible solution:

https://gist.github.com/setrar/77fc1c301266afde9f7f